# How to input the objects to a ArrayList <HashMap<String,Object>>

Tags: java, android, arraylist, hashmap

I have 1 object(Goods) have 2 attributes: `String` and `boolean`. How to input object Goods to `ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>>` ? Because I want input `ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>>` to  SimpleAdapter

```
public class Goods {
    private String goodsName;
    private boolean isCheck = false;
    public String getGoodsName() {
        return goodsName;
    }
    public void setGoodsName(String goodsName) {
        this.goodsName = goodsName;
    }
    public boolean isCheck() {
        return isCheck;
    }
    public void setCheck(boolean isCheck) {
        this.isCheck = isCheck;
    }
}
```

Comment: u want to store the `goodsName` and `isCheck` in array list or the whole `Goods` object ??

Comment: What do you want to store `List` of `Goods` or `List` of `HashMap` ?

Comment: you really want a list of hashmaps for each object? or you just want a list of named objects? this question seems very similar to a response to an earlier question..

Comment: Yes!I want to input whole object Goods ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>>

Comment: what does the hashmap contain?

Comment: there is not enough information to answer this question. You need to specify what the hashmap represents and what the arraylist represents. You are trying to represent 2 dimensions in a 3 dimension space.

Comment: What is SimpleAdapter? This looks weired to me that it require ArrayList of HashMap as the input. HashMap is a complete collection in itself and ArrayList should not be required here.

Answer (score 1):

```
package ngo;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Goods g = new Goods();
        g.setGoodsName("foo");
        g.setCheck(true);

        Map<String, Goods> map = new HashMap<String, Goods>();
        map.put(g.getGoodsName(), g);

        List<Map<String, Goods>> list = new ArrayList<Map<String, Goods>>();
        list.add(map);

        System.out.println(list.get(0).get("foo").isCheck());
    }
}
```

Displays `true`

This should be an acceptable, if simple, structure for the `data` parameter of [SimpleAdapter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SimpleAdapter.html)'s [constructor](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SimpleAdapter.html#SimpleAdapter(android.content.Context,%20java.util.List%3C?%20extends%20java.util.Map%3Cjava.lang.String,%20?%3E%3E,%20int,%20java.lang.String[],%20int[])).  A more exhaustive example of it's use can be found [here](http://eureka.ykyuen.info/2010/01/03/android-simple-listview-using-simpleadapter/)

Answer (score 0):

The following is the basic example, not runnable in itself.

```
ArrayList<HashMap<String, Goods>> listOfMappedGoods = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, Goods>>();

HashMap<String, Goods> goodsList = new HashMap<String, Goods>();

Goods g = new Goods();
g.setGoodsName("foo");
g.setCheck(true);

goodsList.add(g.getGoodsName(), g);
listOfMappedGoods.add(goodsList);
```

The point to note, is that just like every new `Goods` object needs to be created using `new Goods()`, each new `goodsList` needs to be created also using `new HashMap<String, Goods>()`.

If you use something like `goodsList.clear()`, then you are still referring to the original map that was first added to the listOfMappedGoods, so you will clear that instead.